# Properties of complex logarithm

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For proving the complex logarithm identity $logz_1z_2 = logz_1 + logz_2$, most online resources that I've seen have done this:$$logz_1z_2= ln|z_1z_2| + i*arg(z_1z_2)$$
$$=ln|z_1| + i*arg(z_1) + ln|z_2| + i*arg(z_2)$$

Since $ln|z_1| + i*arg(z_1) = logz_1$ and $ln|z_2| + i*arg(z_2) = logz_2$,
$$logz_1z_2 = logz_1 + logz_2$$

But isn't $logz_1 = ln|z_1| + i*arg(z_1) + (2k\pi)i$, where k is any integer? Ideally when k=$0$, shouldn't it reduce to the principal logarithm?

So shouldn't the above identity actually be $logz_1z_2 = Logz_1 + Logz_2$, where $Logz$ denotes the principal logarithm? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Do you distinguish between $\arg$ and $\mathrm{Arg}$?  Which one is single valued (once you pick a branch)?

Answer (score 1):

$\log (z_1z_2)=\log (z_1)+\log (z_2)$ is not true for any branch of logarithm. Take $z_1=z_2=-1$ to see that this fails for the principal branch.

Comment: I agree, but why doesn't the derivation make any distinction between which branch we're talking about in that case?

Comment: If someone is trying to derive something that is false just ignore it. The argument you found on the net is complete non-sense.